# Efficient way to find neighboring cells in a 2d array

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array, coding-efficiency

I have a 2d array of class Tiles. While creating the playfield I have to generate all directly neighboring cells (horizontally, vertically, diagonally). I start by generating the field filling up each cell with a new Tile, than (when that is done) I loop through the 2d array to calculate the neighbors using this piece of loop:

```
int dnDistance= 1; //Direct Neighbor Distance.

for (int iMapY = 0; iMapY < playfieldHeight; iMapY++)
{
    for (int iMapX = 0; iMapX < playfieldWidth; iMapX++)
    {
        for (int yOffset = -dnDistance; yOffset <= dnDistance; yOffset++)
        {
            for (int xOffset = -dnDistance; xOffset <= dnDistance; xOffset++)
            {
                if ((iMapX + xOffset >= 0 && iMapX + xOffset < playfieldWidth) && (iMapY + yOffset >= 0 && iMapY + yOffset < playfieldHeight))
                { 
                    if (!(yOffset == 0 && xOffset == 0))
                    { 
                            playfieldTiles[iMapX, iMapY].dnTiles.Add(playfieldTiles[iMapX + xOffset, iMapY + yOffset]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Using this method, I have to loop through the entire 2d array a second time, creating a for loop, in a for loop, in a for loop, in a for loop which sometimes is quite unclear. There has to be a better way for this, right?

I found [a post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48872167/fastest-way-to-check-each-neighbor-in-2d-array) that looks to be similar but not quite the same, or I don't understand it properly:

Comment: You are implementing the same idea of the post you linked, and to me it seems the way to do it.

Comment: Generally speaking, if you ever end up with more than two or three nested `for` loops you're doing something wrong, unless you're working with a 4D-array or something. @Aybe shows how you can do it in only two `for` loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**When it just works then it's fine !**

Here's a little optimization that makes it easier to **debug**:

```
var playfieldHeight = 5;
var playfieldWidth = 5;
var playfieldTiles = new byte[playfieldWidth + dnDistance * 2, playfieldHeight + dnDistance * 2];
var len1 = playfieldWidth * playfieldHeight;
var len2 = dnDistance * 2 + 1;

for (var i = 0; i < len1; i++)
{
    var ix = i % playfieldWidth;
    var iy = i / playfieldWidth;
    for (var j = 0; j < len2 * len2; j++)
    {
        var jx = j % len2 - dnDistance;
        var jy = j / len2 - dnDistance;
        Console.WriteLine($"x1: {ix}, y1: {iy}, x2: {jx}, y2: {jy}");
    }
}
```

You now have only 2 loops, the field and the neighbors.

You could further optimize it with a single `for` but I believe readability will decrease (inside the loop).

Comment: I think I kinda understand this now that I looked at it the second time. Using the first for loop and the total amout of Tiles in the playfield (25 in this case), you combine the 2 forloops to make it one big one. The ix and iy are iMapX and iMapY. The same thing for for 2 loops to calculate the neighbors. If I am right, this should not impact performance in any way but indeed makes it better to read. I'll mark it as an answer (since I don't think it will get better performance wise) and look into it. Thanks :)

Comment: You welcome, I just did like plotting pixels the old way: converting between an offset to X/Y. It really simplifies debugging as well, as I said it could have been a single loop but then the bounds would be odd, here it's simple and performance should never be a concern unless you loop through an insane amount of items.